# How to create a custom data type in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am not sure if I have formulated the question right, but I want to create a data type Share that would hold a fraction represented as a string "1/4" and would support a couple of utility functions:

1. convert the string fraction to a bigDecimal
2. add one Share object to another and return the summed up bigdecimal
3. subtraction
4. sum up a sequence of Share objects

What is the conventional approach of creating such data type in kotlin?

Here is what I have so far, any suggestions appreciated.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal

class Share(val share : String) {

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun asDecimal(share: String): BigDecimal {
            require(share.length >= 3) { "Cannot convert from string to a BigDecimal, $share must have length >= 3" }
            val numbers = share.split("/")
            val numerator = BigDecimal(numbers[0])
            val denominator = BigDecimal(numbers[1])
            return numerator / denominator
        }
    }

    private inline fun binOp(other: Share, crossinline op: (BigDecimal, BigDecimal) -> BigDecimal): BigDecimal {
        return op(asDecimal(this.share), asDecimal(this.share))
    }

    operator fun plus(other: Share): BigDecimal = binOp(other, BigDecimal::plus)

    operator fun minus(other: Share): BigDecimal = binOp(other, BigDecimal::minus)

    fun Sequence<Share>.sum() : BigDecimal {
        return this.fold(BigDecimal.ZERO, Share::plus)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I would personally make `asDecimal` a normal function inside the class, that works on `this` instead of a given param, so that then you can do `share.asDecimal()` instead of `Share.asDecimal(share)`. That and also, on the `binOp`, you don't use the `other`.

Comment: +1 for @Alex.T's comment. Also, the `sum()` extension function should be outside of the `Share` class, it doesn't make sense to tie it to a `Share` instance

Comment: This looks very similar to a rational number class, which is a common requirement — and a common programming exercise! I've written my own, for example; but there are existing examples on the web you might learn from, e.g. [this one on Rosetta Code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Arithmetic/Rational#Kotlin).